# CSS Dropdown navbar not working with <div> underneath

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project, creating a website for my own personal use.
I have created a horizontal navigationbar at the top of the page with a dropdown menu. It has been working up until now, but after I've created a  tag underneath the navbar, the dropdown menu still shows the dropdown content, but I'm not able to mouseover the content anymore, without the dropdown content disappears.

I've looked at the combination of z-index: and position: but have not been able to make it work yet. Hope somebody can point me in the right direction!

My HTML and CSS:

```css
html, body {
    background-image: url("../css/images/colored_background.jpeg");
}

header {
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 51px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar a, .navdropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li a:hover, .navdropdown:hover .navdropbtn {
  background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);
}

li.navdropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navdropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #333;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.navdropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.navdropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navdropdown:hover .navdropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

main {
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 51px;
}

#mainContent {
  width: 80.2%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -8px;
}

#mainContent h1 {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#edu {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
}

#edu h1 {
  color: yellow;
}

.edubtn {
  background-color: orangered;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 14px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 213.67px;
  text-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li class="navdropdown">
    <a href="" class="navdropbtn">Personal</a>
    <div class="navdropdown-content">
     <a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
     <a href="sites.html">Sites</a>
     <a href="education.html">Education</a>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="mainContent">
      <div id="thisweek">
        <h1>This week</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="nextweek">
        <h1>Next week</h1>
      </div> 
    </section>
      <div id="edu">
          <h1>Educational Tools</h1>
          <div class="container">
            <button class="edubtn">Add Homework</button>
            <button class="edubtn">Add Homework</button>
            <button class="edubtn">Add Homework</button>
            <button class="edubtn">Add Homework</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </main>
```

Hope somebody will help me!